# Efficient way to divide each row of data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data set in data table, but I have created an aggregate table from large table by basically summing the columns by group value:

```
dt <- data.table("grp"=c("a","b","a","c","c","d"), "1"=c(1,45,3,6,2,5), "2"=c(3,36,45,5,12,10), "3"=c(30,3,4,5,2,5), "4"=c(3,3,44,5,2,76), "5"=c(3,3,48,5,2,1), "6"=c(13,73,94,5,2,5))

> dt
   grp  1  2  3  4  5  6
1:   a  1  3 30  3  3 13
2:   b 45 36  3  3  3 73
3:   a  3 45  4 44 48 94
4:   c  6  5  5  5  5  5
5:   c  2 12  2  2  2  2
6:   d  5 10  5 76  1  5
```

I have created an aggregate table

```
dt.aggregate <- dt[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=grp]
   grp  1  2  3  4  5   6
1:   a  4 48 34 47 51 107
2:   b 45 36  3  3  3  73
3:   c  8 17  7  7  7   7
4:   d  5 10  5 76  1   5
```

I want to divide each row based on numbers rows per group from original data table.

for example row1 I want to divide by `nrow(dt[grp=="a"])`, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not change `sum` to `mean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just change `sum` to `mean` as said in a comment. For a more general answer, use  .N

```
dt.aggregate <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){sum(x)/.N}), by = grp]
```

Comment: I get following error: `Error in Summary.factor(c(19370L, 22949L, 15814L, 15188L, 3797L, 20024L,  : 
  sum not meaningful for factors`

Comment: So change the example. You are trying to apply sum on a factor variable. First check every variable is a numeric (use `glimpse` for that).